# $\mathbb{R}/{\sim}$: A Question about the Formal Definition of a Quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

For an equivalence relation $\sim$ what is $\mathbb{R}/{\sim}$? I mean explicitly and formally...

Comment: If $X$ is a set and $\sim$ an equivalence relation on it, $X/\sim$ is the set of all equivalence classes.

Comment: So... The cardinality is smaller?

Comment: Often $|X/\sim|<|X|$ is true, but not always.

Comment: (And this is a subtle thing: In general, we need to use the axiom of choice to show $|X/{\sim}|\le|X|$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define on $\mathbb R$ an equivalence relation $\sim$ that's reflexive, symmetric and transitive and for all $x\in \mathbb R$ let
$$[x]=\{y\in\mathbb R\ |\ y\sim x\}$$
the class of $x$ i.e. the set of element in relation with $x$, hence it isn't difficult to prove that the set of classes denoted by $\mathbb R/\sim$
$$\mathbb R/\sim=\{[x]\ |\ x\in\mathbb R\}$$ 
 forms  a partition of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Could you give an example? What does it mean to say $[3]\in \mathbb{R}/\sim$?

Comment: First you should define an equivalence relation.

Comment: $a\sim b$ if $a-b\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: By definition, $[x]=\{a\in X:a\sim x\}$ is an equivalence class. Since $X/\sim$ is the set of equivalence classes of $X$ and $[x]$ is such a class, we have $[x]\in X/\sim$.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the last part here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443859/revisted-2-are-doubling-and-squaring-well-defined-on-mathbbr-mathbbz

Comment: For $a~b$ if $a-b\in\mathbb Z$, $[3]=\mathbb Z$. And for example $[\frac13]=\{\dots,-\frac53,-\frac23,\frac13,\frac43,\frac73,\dots\}$