# $h:\mathbb{R}_{/\sim}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$: A Bijection from a Quotient Space to the Unit Circle (Geometrically Considered)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, equivalence-relations

---

NOTE: This is not a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443859/revisted-2-are-doubling-and-squaring-well-defined-on-mathbbr-mathbbz).

---

Define a relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{R}$ as follows: for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$a\sim b \iff a-b\in \mathbb{Z}.$$

Let $S=\mathbb{R}_{/\sim}$. That is, $S$ is the set of equivalence classes of elements of $\mathbb{R}$ under the equivalence relation $\sim$.

Let $C=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:x^2+y^2=1\}$, and define $h:S\rightarrow C$ by
$$h([t])=(\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t)).$$

---

TASK: Prove that $h$ is a bijection.

---

I know that I have to show
$$h([t])=h([t'])\implies [t]=[t'],$$
and
$$\forall x\in C \exists x'\in S : h([x'])=x,$$
but I'm not really sure how to go about this.

---

Further question: What is the geometric interpretation of this?

---

WORK: I get that $\mathbb{R}_{/\sim}=\{y\in\mathbb{R} : y-x\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

- $h$ is injective:

  $h([t]=h([t'])\Rightarrow (\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))=(\cos(2\pi t'),\sin(2\pi t'))\Rightarrow e^{2\pi it}=e^{2\pi it'}$  so $t-t'\in \mathbb Z$ and then $[t]=[t']$.
- $h$ is surjective:

Let $(\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))\in C$ then take $[t]\in S$ and we have $h([t])=(\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))$

Geometrically $C$ is the unit circle and we have $h(S)=C$ with $h$ is bijective so we can identify geometrically $S$ to the unit circle.

Comment: Hmm... Uh, thanks?

Comment: When you say "we can identify geometrically $S$ to the unit circle" what do you mean?

Comment: I mean the sentence just write above: there's a bijection between $S$ and $C$ and that's means that $S$ isn't realy a circle but it can be considered as circle.

Comment: How can it be considered a circle is what I am saying?

Comment: There's a similarity between $S$ and $C$ for example we know that the radius of $C$ is $1$ and for $S$ any equivalence class $[y]$ can be represented by $x\in[0,1)$ and the lenght of this interval is $1$.

Comment: So, in terms of isomophism, what can you say about the two sets?

Comment: I mean, what is $S$ geometrically?

Comment: $h$ isn't an isomorphism since it is not a linear map and $S$ and $C$ aren't a vector spaces.

Comment: OK, I misspoke. What I meant was, in terms of one to one correspondence, how is $S$ geometrically related to $C$?

Comment: Let me ask you a question, since you asked: how is $S$ geometrically? Can you draw a picture for $S$?

Comment: No, I can't. Could you help me?

Comment: To draw a picture for $S$ we need for every *point* (element of $S$) a coordinate but the elements of $S$ are the equivalence classes i.e. a set of numbers so the solution is replace every class by its image by $h$ for example the class $[0]$ is replaced by $h([0])=(1,0)$ so we can draw this point since we know its coordinate and thus we can plot a picture for $S$ and this picture is in fact the unit circle. This correspondance is the meaning of $S$ is identified to $C$.

Comment: Now I see. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: You didn't prove surjectivity. You took an element of the image and said that it has a preimage, which is trivial. You have to justify that all elements of $C$ can be written $(\cos 2\pi t, \sin 2\pi t)$ for a $t\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Moreover, when you say "$h$ isn't an isomorphism since it is not a linear map and $S$ and $C$ aren't a vector spaces", I hope it is for the sake of simplification. It is indeed an isomorphism in the category of topological spaces with continuous maps.

Comment: @Antoine For the surjectivity I did, assuming that's an easy fact that $C=\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2=1\}=\{(\cos(2\pi t,\sin(2\pi t)),t\in \mathbb R\}$ and it's indeed a simple parametrization.

Comment: @Sami Ben Romdhane: That was my point! I think that when a question is quite simple, one should better explicit everything in the answer. The OP could misunderstand what proving surjectivity means from your answer. Proving that the image and the "arrival" set coincide is the key point of surjectivity, and this is the one you omitted and called an "easy fact".

Comment: @Antoine If you look at the answer you see that I began by a hint and I had no intention at the outset to give a complete answer and I edited my answer because it seemed to me that the OP is stuck.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: seems we can't find a compromise. I'm just saying that the phrasing "$h$ is surjective: let $(\cos 2\pi t, \sin 2\pi t) \in C$" is error-inducing, and that it skips the point of being surjective. I'm now done.

Answer (score 1):

Algebraically, $S$ is the quotient group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, and the map
$\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \to C$ is a group isomorphism.  To see this, note that
the map $\mathbb{R} \to C$, $t \to e^{2\pi i t}$ is a group homomorphism (the circle in the complex plane is a group under multiplication), and the kernel of this map is precisely $\mathbb{Z}$.  Hence, by the first isomorphism theorem $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \cong C$.

Topologically, the resulting quotient space $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $C$ via the same map.

Comment: Yes, but what is the geometric interpretation?

Comment: @Trancot Take the closed interval $[0, 1]$, and identify the boundary points (i.e glue $0$ to $1$).   Can you see why this space is homeomorphic to the circle?  Can you also see why it's homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}/\sim$?

Comment: Perhaps a picture here would be instructive?